# Angular checkbox input ng-click never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

In my Angular app, I have a form with checkbox inputs:

```
<div ng-repeat="partner in type.partners">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="partner"
        ng-checked="report.participatingPartners[$parent.$index].indexOf(partner) !== -1" 
        ng-click="toggleSelection($parent.$index, $index);">
        <p><span></span>{{partner.name}}<p>
    </label>
</div>
```

And in my controller, just to test this setup:

```
var vm = this;
vm.toggleSelection = toggleSelection;
```

...

```
function toggleSelection(typeId, partnerId) {
    console.log("toggleSelection called");
    console.log(typeId, partnerId);
}
```

This function never gets called when I click the checkbox or its label. Why is that?

I know it's not the `controllerAs` syntax because other functions are working fine.

Comment: If you are using controller as, aren't you missing the name of your controller before the function `toggleSelection(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you probably want to use is `ng-change`. The angular input directive does not have `ng-clicked` or `ng-checked`.

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

Answer (score 1):

By putting the function that you are trying to reference in the `ng-click` onto `$scope` rather than onto `this` the click event should bind as desired.

On the controller...

```
$scope.toggleSelection = toggleSelection;

 function toggleSelection(typeId, partnerId) {
    ...
}
```

On your html...

```
<input type="checkbox" value="partner"
    ng-click="toggleSelection($parent.$index, $index);">
```

Here is a simple [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hally9k/a10tsLr3/2/) of it working.

Comment: Why though? Shouldn't the 'this' syntax work exactly as scope?

Comment: Because `this` refers to the controller object not the `$scope` object. These are two different things. `$scope` is the API that the controller exposes to the view. The view cannot access functions on the controller object. To clarify read this excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699

Answer (score -1):

You have written below code:

```
ng-checked="vm.toggleSelection($parent.$index, $index);"
```

But it should be:

```
ng-checked="toggleSelection($parent.$index, $index);"
```

Just remove "vm"

Comment: Sorry, but that was not it, that was actually a mistake on my copy-pasting.

Comment: @Tiago Please provide code on JS Fiddle or Plunker.

Comment: You say he wrote a line that he did not.. you done messed it up;).